# Config sails connection SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sails.js

Sails version 1.02

I'm from sails version 1.0 and don't use file `connections.js`.
How to config sails connection to SQL Server with sails latest version?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install the adapter: `npm install --save sails-mysql`

Next, in your sails project, in config/datastores.js, in the `default` object, put 
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    url: '',

[(If you are confused about how to construct the url)](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-datastores#?the-connection-url)

This will get you set up in your local environment. To set up for staging or production, do the same on config/staging.js of config/production.js.